# Переопределение стилей CSS

Tags: javascript, css, gwt

У меня на страничке используется `DecoratedTabPanel`. Я написал к нему свои стили. Положил их в файл `styles.css`. Мои стили из `styles.css` применяются не ко всем элементам панели. Если посмотреть в Хроме, то видно, что их переопределяют стили их `standart.css`. Как мне сделать так, чтоб применялись стили из `styles.css`, а не из `standart.css`?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте !important у тех стилей, которые не переопределяются. А вообще, смотря когда подключаются стили, сначала должен подключатся основной стиль, а затем Ваш.

Comment: использование !important крайне не рекомендуется, это плохой тон. Чтобы перебить стиль лучше пологаться на специфичность.

Answer (score 0):

Перед кодом панели, это уже в body вставь стиль или прямо в код или линком, тогда то он уж точно будет последним и переопределит все остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вобщем-то Alex Silaev уже ответил и правильно. Можно еще не подключать standart.css.
А вставка стилей в body или прямо в код (в рифму) - плохой тон.

Answer (score 0):

Смотришь, какой стиль переопределяет твой и делаешь так же. Ну и само собой, твои стили должны быть подключены после стандартных.